# activeTab permission not working if the script executed through background script onUpdate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my background script which executes the `.onUpdate` method and after the `changeInfo.status === 'complete'`, it checks for whether recording is true or false from local storage, if true it executes a script `reloaded.js` and the `reloaded.js` open an iframe of `test.html` which had the js file `test.js`, i.e. in test.js I record the tabcapture screen directly.
Everything works fine if the user invokes the extension on https://example.com and then navigates to https://example.com/foo, the extension will continue to have access to the page. If the user navigates to https://chromium.org, access is revoked.
After researching I found out that we can't use activeTab if the URL has changed from the original domain to something else and user has not performed some actions within that page. How do I solve this issue now?

It lots this error :- **Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured**

`manifest`

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Appoq",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description of my extension",
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "tabs", "tabCapture", "storage"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Click Me"
       
    },
    
    
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": [ "tabcapture.html", "/reload/test.html" ],
          "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
        }
    ]
    
  }
```

`background.js`

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                chrome.storage.local.get('sharingEnabled', function(result) {
                    if (result.sharingEnabled == 'recording') {
                        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                            target: {
                                tabId: tabId
                            },
                            files: ['reloaded.js'],
                        }, () => {});
                    }

                })
            }
```

`test.js`

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabsw) {
      const currentTabId = tabsw[0].id;
      console.log("Current tab ID is: " + currentTabId);
      chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({ consumerTabId: currentTabId }, (streamId) => {
        console.log(streamId)
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          files: ["content.js"],
          target: {tabId: currentTabId}
        }, function () {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, {reloadStreamId: streamId, hello: "getReloadStreamId"});
          

        });
      });
      
      
    });
```

Comment: Do not include filenames in your source code.
The source code is hard to read, so please format it.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto, I formatted the code

Comment: The behavior you described is how activeTab permission works by design. Apparently there's no way to use tabCapture in such scenario. Did you try chrome.desktopCapture?

Comment: @wOxxOm, desktopCapture prompt the user to choose which screen they want to share, how does that gonna work if there is reload, it will prompt everytime, its not a good solution. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: @wOxxOm, I just saw loom upgraded to manifest version 3, and when I click on the record current tab, it opens a pinned tab on the browser inside which (inspecting) there was a file in which they were using tabCapture. I want to implement the same way, how exactly was that working. Can you please explain a bit :)

Comment: What specifically? You can inspect their code in devtools.